# Click OK on alert Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, alerts

Ok so I know there are a number of other answers on this question about alerts in webdriver and I've looked through them but I think my situation is a little different. When I click my submit button I have already switched into 3 frames and then I get the alert, so I tried to switch back to default content and then click the alert using a try catch and alert.accept but it still doesn't click the alert. Code is below. Thanks in advance for your assistance :)

```
public class BookAHoliday {

    public FirstPage completeHolidayFormAndSubmit(String firstDate, String lastDate) {

        sleepsAreBad();
        driver.switchTo().frame("ContainerFrame");
        driver.switchTo().frame("iframeCommunityContainer");
        driver.switchTo().frame("FORMCONTAINER");
        fluentWait(By.id("StartDate_txtInput"));
        firstDayOfLeaveInput.sendKeys(firstDate);
        sleepsAreBad();
        lastDayofLeaveInput.sendKeys(lastDate);

        try {
            submitButton.click();
        } catch (UnhandledAlertException f) {
            try {
                sleepsAreBad();
                driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
                Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
                String alertText = alert.getText();
                System.out.println("Alert data: " + alertText);
                alert.accept();
            } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        sleepsAreBad();

        return PageFactory.initElements(driver, FirstPage.class);
    }


    private void sleepsAreBad() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


public class BaseTest {


    public static WebDriver driver;
    static String driverPath = "C:\\";

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp() {
        System.out.println("****************");
        System.out.println("launching Browser");
        System.out.println("****************");
        // Browser selection

        //Firefox

        DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
        dc.setCapability(CapabilityType.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOUR, UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.IGNORE);
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(dc);

driver.get(URL);

 @AfterClass()
    public static void tearDown() {
        if (driver != null) {
            System.out.println("Closing browser");
            driver.quit();
        }

    }


public class Bookings extends BaseTest{

    @Test(description = "Holiday booking")
    public void CD01() {

        FirstPage firstPage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, FirstPage.class);
        firstPage


                 .logIn("username", "password")
                .clickHolidayLink()
                .completeHolidayFormAndSubmit("12/05/2016", "15/05/2016");



    }
```

[alert box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GsZE.jpg)  Here is the alert box

Comment: You generally do not need to switch to the default content for alerts. Are you sure it's a javascript alert? It works only for those kind of alerts.

Comment: To be honest with you I'm not really sure I've added the picture of the alert box. Is there any easy way to check? firebug doesnt work once the alert is present.

Comment: That does not look like a javascript alert to me.

Comment: If its not javascript what options do I have to click it? As it doesnt look like it has an id at least not one I can check. Really want to avoid using the Enter key!

Comment: So it looks like its Modal dialog, any idea how you click that?

Comment: Is there any exception when you are going to accept alert or not??

Comment: Yes - org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: Modal dialog present: Your request to book holiday has been submitted

Comment: The modal is probably shown as an element on the DOM. Try if you can find the button in it and click on it

Comment: @RemcoW so i did notice an ID in the stacktrace error but when I try and click on it, it doesnt do anything. Do I need to switch to the active element?

Comment: @RemcoW ah never mind that's not the right ID! I'll look in the DOM

Comment: If the modal dialog is in a `<frame>` you'll have to switch to the frame before you can interact with it.

Comment: @Mobrockers would driver.switchTo().activeElement(); work or would I need to find out the id of the frame?

Comment: You need to find out the id or other selector of the frame, if there is one.

Comment: I'm struggling to make heads or tails of the DOM. Is there an easier way to find the element?

Comment: I think you have to implement some wait until alert is present...

Comment: I don't have your DOM so how would I know?

Comment: @Mobrockers yes I'm very aware you dont have my DOM, I meant other than using the DOM is there an easier way to get the element of the Modal Dialog?

Comment: There is no other way no. There would be no way for selenium to know what is a modal dialog as anything can become a modal dialog.

Comment: Ok well thanks for your time and assistance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this when you have got `UnhandledAlertException` in `catch`

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 3000);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
Alert alert = webDriver.switchTo().alert();
alert.accept();
```

May be it will help you...:)

Comment: I thought alert.accept only works with javascript and not modal dialogs?

Comment: Because I have faced this type of multiple issues with dialogs model... and if selenium clearly throws UnhandledAlertException... means it can be handle by selenium...so you can not down vote only with your thought..

Comment: And I didnt down vote you, why would I down vote someone who is trying to help me?

Answer (score 0):

For most alerts you can press enter to press alert`s "ok".

Comment: I did think of that but wanted something a little better than sending the Enter key, will use it as a last resort though :)