# How can selenium find message box?

Tags: javascript, c#, php, vb.net

how Handling of Alerts, vb.net Alerts  Boxes in selenium web driver and how find it in web driver ..... i want it in vb.net
I need to click the 'Ok' button inside an alert window with a Selenium command.using vb.net

It's possible the click the 'Ok' button? If so, can someone provide me an example of the Selenium IDE command?

Comment: You mean `alert()` types? Like: [Click OK on alert Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37588384/click-ok-on-alert-selenium-webdriver)